# Change image using innerHTML and show back and previous button according to result

Tags: php, innerhtml

I have images of alphabets. I want to to change the image from A to B when press next button usin innerHTML. When it is "A", only next button should display.When it is "Z", only previous button should displayed. else  both button button should display..Which code will work in php??

Comment: For me it looks like you want to reload images without reloading the page right? Then you should aim in JS not PHP. Do you have any code ore something to work on? Or do you expect us to do the dirty work? :D

Answer (score 0):

In your case JS looks a bit better but with PHP a short hint for you. Build an array and look which image is shown in the array (the position). Then you can check if you are at the end of the array in that case the index is the length of the array.

Then you can work with if else. So i don't give you the exact code Stackoverflow is to learn and find solutions for existing problems.

```
$alphabet = array(
    0 => 'pathtoA',
    1 => 'PathtoB'
    ....
);
```

So when you now print **A** for example you know that its the key 0 and that 0 is the first position so you can show only the next button with an if.

```
count($alphabet);
```

With count you get the length and you can look if your current id is the last element and you show only the preview button.

This is a very simple solution but i think if you read a but you get a solution on your own.

Comment: Yes. I have use JS to change the image. Here i give you a code.         <img src='' width='4%' onClick='prev()' id='pre'>
<img src='1.gif' width=620px height=320px id='img1'>
<img src='' width='4%' onClick='next()' id='nxt'></a>

Comment: Yes. I have use JS to change the image. Here i give you a code.         <img src='' width='4%' onClick='prev()' id='pre'>
<img src='1.gif' width=620px height=320px id='img1'>
<img src='' width='4%' onClick='next()' id='nxt'></a>                                                 Here the first and last image is the  arrow image indicates previous and next. and the middle image is the alphabet image which are saved as A as 1.gif, B as 2.gif and so on.and the following are JS function.